# Invariant Violation: Avatar(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing

Tags: reactjs

```js
renderIconWrapper = (altText,imgSrc) => {
    return (
           <IconWrapper>
            <DoctorImage alt={altText} src={imgSrc}/>
          </IconWrapper>
        )
  }
render(){
const {gender, detailsGender, providerDetailTypeNm} = this.props;
if (providerDetailTypeNm === "Professional") {
      if (gender === "M" || detailsGender === "Male") {
        this.renderIconWrapper('male-avatar',maleAvatar)
      } else if (gender === 'F') {
        this.renderIconWrapper('female-avatar',femaleAvatar)
      }
    } else if (providerDetailTypeNm === 'Facility' || providerDetailTypeNm === 'Supplier Business') {
      this.renderIconWrapper('fa-hospital',faHospital)
      
    } else if (providerDetailTypeNm === 'Group') {
       this.renderIconWrapper('fa-users',faUsers)
    } else {
      this.renderIconWrapper('fa-users',faUsers)
    }
 }
```

I am getting Invariant Violation: ...): Nothing was returned from render.
Could some one let me know what is the errors into the code I think I am missing something or some error into the syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `renderIconWrapper` method returns a JSX element, you are not returning the result of it from render. Call `return` from render to return the result of `this.renderIconWrapper`

```js
renderIconWrapper = (altText,imgSrc) => {
    return (
           <IconWrapper>
            <DoctorImage alt={altText} src={imgSrc}/>
          </IconWrapper>
        )
  }
render(){
   const {gender, detailsGender, providerDetailTypeNm} = this.props;
   if (providerDetailTypeNm === "Professional") {
      if (gender === "M" || detailsGender === "Male") {
        return this.renderIconWrapper('male-avatar',maleAvatar)
      } else if (gender === 'F') {
        return this.renderIconWrapper('female-avatar',femaleAvatar)
      }
   } else if (providerDetailTypeNm === 'Facility' || providerDetailTypeNm === 'Supplier Business') {
      return this.renderIconWrapper('fa-hospital',faHospital)
      
    } else if (providerDetailTypeNm === 'Group') {
       return this.renderIconWrapper('fa-users',faUsers)
    } else {
      return this.renderIconWrapper('fa-users',faUsers)
    }
 }
```